# Unable to link to next page using Firebase key

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to link to the next page using the firebase key.

Once I scan the QR code, containing the firebase key, it should lead to the next page, which is detailpage.dart

The Scanning of the QR code works as I tried displaying the value inside with a toast.
The value that I am able to retrieve is, -Mx4_yXjX50ghfuHxqK2

Ideally, once I scan the QR code, I will be shown the items in Location 1.

[image]

The error when i scan :

[image]

How i called the Firebase:

```
final database = FirebaseDatabase(
  databaseURL:
  "https://trackkit-a5cf3-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app")
  .reference()
  .child("NTU");
```

My scanning code :

```
      Future<void> scanQR() async {
    String barcodeScanRes;
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    try {
      barcodeScanRes = await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode(
          '#ff6666', 'Cancel', true, ScanMode.QR);
      print(barcodeScanRes);
    } on PlatformException {
      barcodeScanRes = 'Failed to get platform version.';
    }

    // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
    // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
    // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _scanBarcode = barcodeScanRes;
    });
    barcode = _scanBarcode;
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => detailsPage(
            referenceName: barcode,


          )),
    );
  }
```

My detailpage.dart (Next page)

```
    
    class detailsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  detailsPage(
      {Key? key,
        this.heroTag,
        this.labPlace,
        this.foodName,
        this.barcode,
        this.onValueChanged,
        required this.referenceName})
      : super(key: key);

  final heroTag;
  final labPlace;
  final foodName;
  final barcode;
  final onValueChanged;
  String referenceName;



  @override
  _detailsPageState createState() => _detailsPageState();
}
```

I am able to display the items if I don't go through the scanning method, but the scanning method bring an unknown error, that I am unable to solve for days! Any help is greatly appreciated!